# Code sharing and review question unfairly closed

Tags: discussion

I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314701/sending-html-email-from-t-sql and I was asked, "er.. what's the question?"

The post was closed shortly thereafter.

The question was clearly "Does anyone have any other ideas on a better way to acheive a similar result?"
Despite the fact that there was a question, I find it that such a well constructed post with decent, usable code, was receive with such rudeness.

Why should I bother contributing to Stack Overflow?
If no one wanted to further elaborate on better solutions to the problem, then let the post become a tumble weed. No need to close it, and treat the poster (me) so rudely.

Perhaps Stack Overflow should consider *warning* the user first, giving them appropriate opportunity to fix the post.

Comment: Your question was easy to miss in that wall of code. I too saw it, read the first line and thought you were just posting the code to share it (which isn't how SO functions, the code would need to be added as an answer). If you are looking for someone to review your code I believe this is the place http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @Martin

I appreciate that.

I might just avoid SO... Honestly Im offended even that the title of this Meta post was changed, and 'Jeff Atwood' has apperently edited my post, and I have no idea what was changed.

Political mine field this place is. But hey, it's a big internet...

Comment: @Michael: You can [click on the time of the last edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/105195/revisions) to see the changes. He edited your inflammatory title. If you're not comfortable with people editing your posts, you're on the wrong sites, because that's an important part of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 18):

Well, first of all, **it was asked on the wrong site and *migrated* to Stack Overflow**.

You asked this question on Super User, which has just about zero code on the entire site. Per [the Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software

Do you see "programmer" there anywhere? Do any of the questions on the front page of http://superuser.com look like programming questions?

Second, **there is no actual question there**. Per [the Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) we expect questions to be, well, *questions*:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Buried in the *middle* of your "question" is this single line:

> Any way I wonder if anyone might have some suggestions on an easier way to do it

Which is still kind of off-topic; if you need a code review of functioning code head to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Otherwise, you could possibly re-ask and break your question into a proper question and self-answer pair per https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: "Buried": Read the post! God forbid sometimes you have to look for detail! No probs: I'll check out code review. AFAICT, these sites are overrun with politics: most forums would allow a perfectly decent post, and just let it fade away of no one attendended it. My post got DOWN VOTED. Someone posted "UMM wheres the question", quite rudely, and then the post was closed without warning. Whatever. Delete it if you must.

Comment: @Michael: you're not on a forum. (Here, on superuser or on stackoverflow). Insulting the people who answer and maintain those Q&A sites won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like useful information.  I've done the same thing, but the trick on these sites is to post a question, then post an answer with the good information.

It will then be there easy to find in the future.

Comment: lol

Well actually it does turn up on google fortunatley. Not for long maybe?? Does closed mean it will be archived or something?

Any hoo, I did phrase a question in there, but I forgot the question mark..

But I could have been warned if you know what I mean.

Comment: BTW, my first post on stack overflow got awarded 'tumble weed'

Kinda funny I guess, but then again not really.